# RSS Feed Library not working

Tags: android, rss

I'm using this library in my android project to read an RSS Feed:

https://github.com/matshofman/Android-RSS-Reader-Library

Right now I'm just starting off and I am trying to get any RSS feed to work and give out a single String (a Title) and show it in a textview. If that works, I'll go on to add it in a listview then open in a different window.

But as it is, the code below does not work:

```
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    try {
         url = new URL("http://feeds.feedburner.com/ndtv/TqgX");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        t.setText("URLerror");
    }
    try {
        RssFeed feed = RssReader.read(url);
        ArrayList<RssItem> rssItems = feed.getRssItems();
        String sn = feed.getTitle();
        t.setText(sn);
        for (RssItem rssItem : rssItems) {
            Log.i("RSS Reader", rssItem.getTitle());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Error", "eror");
        t.setText("RSSerror");
    }
```

On running the Textview gets set to "RSSerror" so the problem is in the 2nd try block. Below is the official example from the library:

```
   URL url = new URL("http://example.com/feed.rss");
RssFeed feed = RssReader.read(url);

ArrayList<RssItem> rssItems = feed.getRssItems();
for(RssItem rssItem : rssItems) {
    Log.i("RSS Reader", rssItem.getTitle());
}
```

Am I using the wrong format for the RSS URL? or something else?

Here's the RSSReader class:

public class RssReader {

```
public static RssFeed read(URL url) throws SAXException, IOException {

    return read(url.openStream());

}

public static RssFeed read(InputStream stream) throws SAXException, IOException {

    try {

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
        RssHandler handler = new RssHandler();
        InputSource input = new InputSource(stream);

        reader.setContentHandler(handler);
        reader.parse(input);

        return handler.getResult();

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        throw new SAXException();
    }

}
```

I've got 3 others, RSSItem, RSSHandler and RSSFeed which are, as far as I know, working great. What could be causing the problem?

If you need the other classes, kindly ask (Alternatively, look up the giuhub project)

Any input will be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4):

Try this library:
https://github.com/Pkmmte/PkRSS

It works with most RSS feeds by default and downloads efficiently but it also allows you to plug in your own Parser and make it.

For your code, something like this would work:

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
try {
    url = new URL("http://feeds.feedburner.com/ndtv/TqgX");
} catch (Exception e) {
    t.setText("URLerror");
}
try {
    List<Article> rssItems = PkRSS.with(this).load(url).get();
    Article article = rssItems.get(0);
    t.setText(article.getTitle());
    for (Article item : rssItems) {
        Log.i("PkRSS", item.toShortString());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i("Error", "eror");
    t.setText("RSSerror");
}
```

Although you may want to load these asynchronously using `PkRSS.with(this).load(url).callback(this).async();`

Comment: @Pkmmte  we cant use URL object inside the load function. and other thing is rssItem is always null. please give a solution for that

Comment: @Pkmmte It'll be helpful if you can provide a good easy to use example for your library. FYI, EarlParser loading time is less compared to PkRss.

Comment: @Pkmmte above example gives android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @Krishan Use async method of PkRss, implement void OnPreLoad(), void OnLoaded(List<Article> articleList) and public void OnLoadFailed() methods. Where articleList is what you are looking for.

Comment: Nice one, thanks! I like the "Square-Picasso-style" chaining methods. :)

Comment: @Arpan The above example does that on purpose. I just tweaked the code in his question to use the library. Since he was already doing networking, I assumed his code ran in a background thread.

Comment: @Pkmmte yeah, they're great! Not sure if you saw it but I sent you a pull request for a small update. I didn't notice the last version and I was missing the Callback in the main thread, so I guess it's important to notice the users about the 1.2. :)